# File upload not working since 22.04 upgrade

Tags: 22.04

This behaviour has been around for a while for me, specifically ever since I updated to 22.04 from 20.04, and may be related to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1970148.

However, for me, when I click on upload or download file (for instance, by visiting [https://ps.uci.edu/~franklin/doc/file_upload.html](https://ps.uci.edu/%7Efranklin/doc/file_upload.html) in google chrome) nothing pops up. There are no errors in the dev console or terminal.

I upgraded to 22.04 the default way, didn't install anything fancy other than the default.

Possible fixes I tried:

- `sudo apt install xdg-desktop-portal-gnome` and reboot
- Disabled hardware acceleration in chrome and rebooted chrome
- Toggling hardware acceleration multiple times and rebooting chrome
- Disable chrome apps (I have none)
- Opening in Incognito Mode so that extensions are disabled

Environment:

- Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
- Google Chrome: Version 106.0.5249.103 (Official Build) (64-bit)
- Firefox: Version 105.0.2
- Desktop Environment: ubuntu:GNOME
- File Manager: Nautilus

Comment: I haven't confirmed if it's a bug, hence why I am asking it here. The link to the bug report that I posted might be relevant, and it might not be. The bug report specified that web browsers froze when trying to download/upload a file. For me, the browser simply doesn't load the file select dialog.

Comment: I'm just asking to see if A) Anyone else has experience this specific issue or knows of a solution, or B) Whether there is a known bug report specifically about this issue that I can post to, or C) figure out if I should submit a bug report to ubuntu

Comment: I got an "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN" when trying to upload to the site you mentioned with a Google Chrome that otherwise downloads/uploads perfectly. So, this suggests the problem is in the remote site.

Comment: It doesn't work on any website for me. Try https://viljamis.com/filetest/

Comment: In general, any `<input type="file">` are non-functional, as tested manually by writing some html